# System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 010000a4

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a Xamarin mobile app in Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10).
Calling WCF web services the following error shows up, please guide me if you have a solution.

```
 void SubmitEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // DisplayAlert("Status","Record Found","OK"); 
            CallWCF();
        }
        private void CallWCF()
        {
           var address = new EndpointAddress("http://url.in/service.svc");
            WSHttpBinding bind = new WSHttpBinding();

           var wcf = new ServiceReference1.serviceQueryClient(bind, address);

            var _rVE = new ServiceReference1.ReceiptVaahanQueryEntity();                

            wcf.SBSReceiptVaahanQueryAsync(_rVE);

        }
```

Error:

> System.TypeLoadException   Message=Could not resolve type with token
>   010000a4 from typeref (expected class
>   'System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding' in assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')

Comment: Clean all the binary files in your project, make sure all projects reference the same versions of Xamarin and the same version of other assemblies, then rebuild the whole solution.

Comment: In Debug mode by selecting Linking: "SDK Assemblies Only" in Project Properties -> Android Options -> Linker.